# How to use same visual states over and over without having to copy and paste them each time in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, visualstates

I am using the `Mahapps.Metro` framework and more specifically the `transitionintcontentcontrol` and the "Custom" transition.

If I want to use the same custom transition, I have to create a collection of all the custom visual states I want to use for each `transitionintcontentcontrol`. If I give each visual state the same name, even if it's on a different control, it pops up saying that that *name already exists*. If I remove the collection definition, it says that it *doesn't exist*.

How do I declare this custom visual state as a resource and then use it in XAML AS the visual state I want without needlessly copying and pasting?

TransitionintContentControl Example:
http://pastebin.com/VbBh5NT8

Comment: Please add your code to the question and highlight the problematic part. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Just paste your code and add comments on which line(s) causes an error.